# How to feed integer encoded tokens and labels in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How to feed data to tensorflow where there are 2 lists of list of integer encoded inputs and labels. Both the list are of variable lengths. 
Example
input [[1 2 3] [4 5]]
label [[0 0 0] [1 1]]

how to feed given data in tensorflow and do i need sequence length for labels too or just input.

Comment: Are you training a logistic regression classifier with tensorflow? Perhaps a variational autoencoder? I guess you're trying to train an RNN, but you need to specify what you're doing. Tensorflow is a general purpose math library. To define a variable length sequence you generally need to pad with zeros and specify to `tf.nn.dyanmic_rnn` what your sequence lengths are so it knows how to compute the losses appropriately. Here's a good tutorial: https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html

Comment: Dear David,I am trying to build Named Entity Recognition using RNN where I am stuck at integer encoded sentences and tags respectively. I dont know how to feed this data into tensorflow and do I need to pad even labels?